# Solving $t(n)=t(\frac{n}{5})+t(\frac{n}{17}) +n$ using master theorem

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, master-theorem

Here is what I've tried ,I have bounded $t(n)$ from above and below 
 like so $t_1(n)=2t(\frac{n}{17})+n\leq t(n)\leq t_2(n)=2t(\frac{n}{5})+5$.

Then i have solved $t_1(n)$ and $t_2(n)$ by the master theorem:

for $t_1(n)$ let $a=2,b=17,f(n)=n$.

Then $f(n)^{log_b{a}}=n^{log_{17}{2}}=\Omega(n^{log_{17}{2}+\epsilon}),$for $\epsilon=1-log_{17}{2}>0$,and $a\cdot f(n/b)=2\cdot\frac{n}{17}\leq c\cdot n$ for a constant $c=0.5<1$.Then by case 3 of the master theorem $t_1(n)=\Omega(n).$

Similarly for $t_2(n)$ let $a=2,b=5,f(n)=n$ ,then $n^{log_{5}{2}}=\Omega(n^{log_{5}{2}+\epsilon}) ,\epsilon=1-log_{5}{2}$ ,$2\cdot \frac{n}{5}\leq c\cdot n$ for c=0.5.By case 3 of the master theorem $t_2(n)=\Theta(n).$

Therefore $t(n)=\Theta(n)$.Am i doing this correctly ?,if not then please tell me where did i go wrong about this.

Comment: No; unless you have another added factor at the end, both bounds will be constant. Also, please don't paste raw LaTeX here, it is very hard to read.

Comment: Am I on the right path if I bind t(n) from above and below correctly ?

Comment: As I said, no. The general idea is correct, but it will not work for this case. It will work if you have e.g. `T(n) = T(n/5) + T(n/17) + n`, i.e. another factor.

Comment: This is embarrassing  but i just noticed that i wrote t(n) incorrectly ,i have fixed it now sorry.

Comment: Now it is correct, yes. Both limits are linear.

Comment: So to sum up t(n)=theta(n) correct ?